# Ajax: How do I control which click the Ajax posts on?

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax

Hi I have a Ajax form which needs to post when the follwoing button is clicked:

```
<div id="divaddtocartbtn">
     <input type="image" class="buynow" id="imgaddtocart" alt="Add to Cart" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/odditiesaddtobasketbutton.png" />
</div>
```

However I also have a counter as follows:

```
<div class="box">
   <label for="qty">
   <abbr title="Quantity">Qty</abbr></label>
    <input id="qty" value="0" />
    <button id="down" onclick="modify_qty(-1)">-1</button>
    <button id="up" onclick="modify_qty(1)">+1</button>
</div>
```

http://www.codecademy.com/courses/a-simple-counter/0#!/exercises/0 - simple counter

However as this is within the Ajax form when i try to click the + and - to increase/decrease the counter an Ajax post happens.  How do i seperate the input so that the Ajax post only happens on the add to basket click?

I was thinking that i need to put the counter outside of the Ajax form but I need to take the quantity that is selected within the ajax post.

```
Ajax.BeginForm("ThreeInOneBin2", new AjaxOptions() {
    HttpMethod = "POST"
});
```

Please see below for full code:

```
<div class="ThreeInOneBin2middle">
            <ul>
                <% if (Model.ProductNotFound)
                   { %>
                <!-- List the retailers as we have none in stock -->
                <%= Html.WidgetProductNotFoundList(Model) %>
                <% }
                   else
                   { %>
                <% using (Html.BeginForm())
                   {%>
                <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
                <%= Html.WidgetProductFoundListThreeStageBin2(Model)%>
                <div class="stepFour">
                    <% if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Confirmation))
                       {
                           Ajax.BeginForm("ThreeInOneBin2", new AjaxOptions()
                                                          {

                                                              HttpMethod = "POST"
                                                          });
                           { %>
                    <img src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/DoveStep3message.png" alt="" />

                   <%-- This is the quantity--%>
                    <div class="box">
                        <label for="qty">
                            <abbr title="Quantity">
                                Qty</abbr></label>
                        <input id="qty" value="0" />
                        <button id="down" onclick="modify_qty(-1)">
                            -1</button>
                        <button id="up" onclick="modify_qty(1)">
                            +1</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="uandp">
                        <p>
                            <input type="text" name="username" class="txtUsername" id="email" value="Username" />
                            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Email", "Please enter a valid Email") %>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="txtPassword" value="Password" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="rightaddtocart">
                        <div id="divaddtocartbtn">
                            <input type="image" class="buynow" id="imgaddtocart" alt="Add to Cart" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/odditiesaddtobasketbutton.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <% } %>
                    <% }
                       else
                       { %>
                    <p>
                        <%-- <%= ViewBag.Confirmation %>--%>
                        <img class="divAdded" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/Basketmessage.png"
                            alt="Added to Basket" />
                    </p>
                    <% } %>
                </div>
                <% } %>
                <% } %>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Tagged "jquey" - where's the jQuery?

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as an "Ajax form". A form's submission can be intercepted, such that an Ajax request can be made instead, drawing on form-derived data. Once you grasp this point, you will be well on the way to answering your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers assume that any `<button></button>` within a form is a submit button. Such buttons will submit the form unless measures are taken to make them behave otherwise.

It is also good practice to attach event handlers in javascript/jQuery, rather than in the HTML.

You should get the correct behaviour from your "+" and "-" buttons as follows :

HTML :

```
<button id="down">-1</button>
<button id="up">+1</button>
```

javascript:

```
$("#down").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    modify_qty(-1);
});
$("#up").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    modify_qty(1);
});
```

`event.preventDefault()` is a jQuery command that causes the natural action of DOM elements to be suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

My suggest is to use ajax with jquery. Below code may helpful for you.

```
<script>

$("#imgaddtocart").click(function(event) {

event.preventDefault(); 

var myForm = $(this).parent( 'form:first' );
var url = myForm.attr("action");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    data:myForm.serialize(),

    success:function(data)
    {
        alert(data.message);
    },
    error:function()
    {
        alert("error");
    }
}); 
/*End : Ajax*/


});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks shah i ll see if i can get that working i think i need to understand ajax a bit more.

Comment: I can t quite get this working i ve added that in but it still posts when i click the other buttons